# How would you evaluate $\int_0^1 \sqrt{2+e^{2t}+e^{-2t}}$dt

Tags: calculus

Alternatively, is there a better way to find the arc length of the vector function $\mathbf{r}(t)=\langle\sqrt2t,e^t,e^{-t}\rangle$ for $t\in[0,1]$? My work: $\mathbf{r}'(t)=\langle\sqrt{2},e^{t},-e^{-t}\rangle$, so $|\mathbf{r}'(t)|=\sqrt{2+e^{2t}+e^{-2t}}$, and the arc length is given by $\int_0^1\sqrt{2+e^{2t}+e^{-2t}}dt$. I think I've done this right, but I cannot figure out how to evaluate that integral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $2 + e^{2t} + e^{-2t} = (e^t + e^{-t})^2$

Comment: Thank you! Gotta brush up on my precalc I guess.

Comment: @user161997: sure is.

Comment: Yes,  the standard "Science" calculus course is, among other things, an exercise in basic geometry/trig/algebra. Might be the most important part.